Reducing Token Generation Delay with Azure.Identity Package
I am encountering a significant delay when generating access tokens using the Azure.Identity (version 1.11.0) package in my application. The scenario involves using a ChainedTokenCredential class with two token credentials:

Managed Identity Credential with client ID.
Default Credential.

My intention is that if the first token credential (Managed Identity Credential) fails to generate a token, the second one (Default Credential) should be used immediately. However, I've noticed that even though the first credential fails as expected, there is a delay of approximately 5 minutes before the token is generated using the second credential.
I suspect that there might be a retry policy in place that is causing this delay. Is there a way to disable or configure this retry policy so that the application switches to the second credential without such a delay?
Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using:
     private static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
 {
     AccessToken token =
          new ChainedTokenCredential(
             new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId: "<client-id>"), 
             new DefaultAzureCredential()) // or AzureCliCredential(),VisualStudioCredential()... so on
         .GetToken(
             new TokenRequestContext(
                 new[] { "https://storage.azure.com/.default" },
                 isCaeEnabled: false
             ));

     return token.Token;
 }


DefaultAzureCredential is itself essentially a ChainedTokenCredential that attempts Managed Identity first. Have you tried configuring individual credentials after the MI credential instead of DefaultAzure?

Yes, I've tried the code below, and it also takes around 5 minutes:
AccessToken token =
await new DefaultAzureCredential(
new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
ManagedIdentityClientId = ""
})
.GetTokenAsync(
new TokenRequestContext(
new[] { "https://storage.azure.com/.default" }
));
But I believe this is the same as the one I posted in the question because in this case, ManagedIdentityCredential will also be executed first.

That's not what I meant. I meant that you could try new ChainedTokenCredential(new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId: "your-client-id"), new AzureCliCredential(), ...) (add credentials you want to try as fallback)

Yes, it also takes around 5 minutes. I don't think it's different from the one I've shared. The bottleneck seems to be the ManagedIdentityCredential step, as it's taking time.

@juunas
If I specify these options in managed identity token credential new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId:"<client-id>", new TokenCredentialOptions {     Retry =     {         MaxRetries = 0,         Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),         NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)     } })
It is failing immediately. I'm not sure about the Network timeout option and how to set its value, by default it was 100 seconds.

I want to confirm one thing, is ManagedIdentityCredential designed to fail to generate a token and DefaultAzureCredential designed to generate a token successfully? If yes, can we put DefaultAzureCredential before ManagedIdentityCredential. By the way, just like juunas said DefaultAzureCredential already contains Managed Identity auth, why we need to put them into one chain?

@TinyWang I've edited my question with, new ChainedTokenCredential(              new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId: "<client-id>"),               new VisualStudioCredential())          .GetToken(              new TokenRequestContext(                  new[] { "https://storage.azure.com/.default" },                  isCaeEnabled: false              ))
It is also taking the same amount of time.

In my humble opinion, it shouldn't take so much time for the authentication, so that we might figure out which option brings the traffic. If it's ManagedIdentityCredential causing the issue, then is it possible to confirm it and then troubleshoot why it cost so much time? Or we exclude this scheme?
